# Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region enclosed by the lines...

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region enclosed by the lines $y=x$, $y=4-x$, and $y=0$ about the x-axis.

I can use any method for this problem, and I began by graphing. Which lead to a triangle over the $x$-axis. I'm really lost on how to do this, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

as you see the intersection point of the lines is $(2,2)$ then volume is $$V= \pi\int\limits_{0}^2x^2dx+\pi\int\limits_{2}^4(4-x)^2dx$$ then you can conclude.

Comment: Can you explain why it is that you square the x and (4-x), and also why you multiply both by pi?

Comment: volume of a rotated region is calculated (with disc method) by the formula $$V=\pi\int\limits_{a}^{b}(f(x))^2dx$$

Comment: you can search on internet by "disc method"

Comment: this true i read it x=0, +1